Disadvantages to using callback for async chrome.tabs queries vs. the official example
See the following code as an example:
var activeTab = function(callBack)
{
    let queryOptions = {lastFocusedWindow:true, active:true};
    chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions, function(tabs)
    {
        for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++)
            callBack(tabs[i]);

        // should be same as calling callBack(tabs[0]);
    });
};

activeTab(cb => chrome.tabs.sendMessage(cb.id, {msg:content}));

versus the official example:
  async function activeTab()
  {
    let queryOptions = {lastFocusedWindow:true, active:true};
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
    return tab;
  }

  activeTab().then((cb) => { chrome.tabs.sendMessage(cb.id, {msg:content}); });

Just wondering if there's any issues doing it one way vs the other way ...
(I've also seen it done with promises)
I have tried the await method before and I'm pretty sure I've run into an issue
but it might've been only in manifest v2,
where there was no matching signature calling tabs.query ...
I know the 1st example seems to work pretty well, and callback looks simpler to me :)

There's no difference in this isolated example, but when doing other things await is much more convenient. Note that you can simplify the second example as chrome.tabs.sendMessage((await activeTab()).id, msg)

"should be same as calling callBack(tabs[0])" - but is it?

callBack(tabs[0]) and "for loop" seems the same as this particular tabs.query should always return array of 1 or 0 ... hmm.

Of course chrome.tabs.sendMessage((await activeTab()).id, msg) would only work in manifest v3 I'm assuming ...
